Mesh is unaffected by lighting when hair particles are turned on in eevee
I've been modeling for a decent amount of time now, but this is my first time messing with hair particles.
I'm using them to add a furry texture to a character model. But when they're visible, it makes the mesh be unaffected by the lighting for some reason? It seems to work fine in Cycles but I'm hoping there's a way to fix this for eevee.
I've tried looking over the particle settings to try and fix it, and I have tried to adjust the materials themselves but I've had no success.
[][
This is being modeled in Blender 4.1 for reference and here's the blend file so you can see what I mean for yourself.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Whn7vZyYLODDGfeaeOCYwlJyqxz5V8ur/view?usp=sharing
I apologize if this is somewhat confusing, this is my first time asking others to help me figure out problems.
